# Swift NSFetchedResultsController not sectioning based on sectionNameKeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<StoryTemplatePack> =
    {
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

        var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<StoryTemplatePack> = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: self.createFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionnum", cacheName: nil)
        frc.delegate = self

        return frc
}()

// FetchedResultsController: Create Request
func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<StoryTemplatePack> {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<StoryTemplatePack>(entityName: "StoryTemplatePack")

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "productidentifier != nil")

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "isfeatured", ascending: false),
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "ispurchased", ascending: true),
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    ]


    return fetchRequest
}
```

The results should be sectioned according to the `sectionnum` property on StoryTemplatePack (which is a transient property calculated in code).

When I loop over the results of the NSFetchedResultsController it shows the correct section numbers and story pack names. There should be 3 sections, but the FRC is reporting only 1 section. The dumped results also show that I'm sorting the results correctly so that the section values are monotonically increasing.

```
---- dumping frc, num sections: 1
    section 0 pack Incredible Journeys
    section 0 pack Out for a Date
    section 0 pack Party Time
    section 1 pack Holiday Craziness
    section 1 pack In the Office
    section 1 pack On the Internets
    section 1 pack On the Job
    section 1 pack School Daze
    section 1 pack Social Networking
    section 1 pack TV Troubles
    section 1 pack Technology Takes Over
    section 2 pack Christmas Shenanigans
---- done dumping
```

`self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count` is returning 1 when it should return 3.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309424/1187415: The sectionNameKeyPath must also be the first sort descriptor.

Comment: @MartinR It doesn't need to BE the first sort descriptor, it just needs to have sort descriptors that give the same ordering that matches up with the sectionNameKeyPath (which your link also describes `(or a key that generates the same relative ordering)`). And my sorting -does- match up with the sectionNameKeyPath as shown when I dump all of the results.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was simplifying. – Your first sort descriptor is based on "isfeatured" – does that generate the same relative ordering as the sectionNameKeyPath? Does it work if you add a first sort descriptor using sectionNameKeyPath?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, as I explicitly said in my post, my results are sorted correctly. The 3 sort descriptors I use produce the same ordering as the values in my `sectionnum` property. You can see it in the dumped results because the section numbers are sorted correctly.

Comment: The first sort descriptor *alone* must generate the ordering compatible with the sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: @MartinR That doesn't make any sense. Can you point me to the documentation that says that?

Comment: @MartinR *sigh* It -does- seem to behave that way, but that doesn't make ANY sense. Why would it isolate some of the sort descriptors from the others? Then it would need to create multiple queries and db cursors. That just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller/1622282-init: *“If this key path is not the same as that specified by the first sort descriptor in fetchRequest, they must generate the same relative orderings.”* – I cannot tell you why it is implemented that way.